# Using a variable as the name of a TeamCity property

Tags: teamcity

I have the following powershell script:

```
$triggerBy = "Finish Build Trigger; Aed / My Application / Service / My Application Service, build #4.1.2.41"
$buildId = $triggerBy -replace 'Finish Build Trigger; ', '' -replace ', build #.*', '' -replace '( \/ )', '_' -replace ' ', ''
```

When this runs, `$buildId` is set to `Aed_MyApplication_Service_MyApplicationService`.

I then want to get value of the variable `%dep.Aed_MyApplication_Service_MyApplicationService.build.number%`.  But I need to use the value of `$buildId` for the middle part of that.

**Is there a way to say $buildNumber = `%dep.$buildId.build.number%` and TeamCity recognize that `$buildId` should be expanded before it evaluates the variable?**

Answer (score 1):

No, sadly there is no way to force TeamCity to evaluate the build lazily.

If this is a `$triggerBy` "switch/case" kind of choice though, you could create a build step (at the beginning of the build), that will :

- test if your calculated `$buildId` is `Aed_MyApplication_Service_MyApplicationService`
- `if` it is, the following should enable you to use `%myDepBuildNumber%` in the next build steps :

```
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='myDepBuildNumber' value='%dep.Aed_MyApplication_Service_MyApplicationService.build.number%']"
```

- `else` do nothing.

Repeat this `if`/`else` for any `$triggerBy` case.

If you get an error for unset `%dep.Aed_MyApplication_Service_MyApplicationService.build.number%` : setting this parameter should fix the issue. (e.g. if your build and `Aed_MyApplication_Service_MyApplicationService` both belong to `Aed_MyApplication_Service` then declare the parameter here).